# Same integral diverges for different limits?

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I was investigating convergence of such an integral:

$\int_{1}^\infty $$\frac{dx}{x(1+x)} $

I used comparison test:

$\int_{1}^\infty $$\frac{dx}{x(1+x)} $ < $\int_{1}^\infty $$\frac{dx}{x^2} $

to prove it converges. But for an integral

$\int_{0}^\infty $$\frac{dx}{x(1+x)} $

it does not work as $\int_{0}^\infty $$\frac{dx}{x^2} $ diverges too. Which test should I use then?

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_{1}^\infty $$\frac{dx}{x^2}$ converges though.

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I was able to use the comparison  test. $\int_{0}^\infty $$\frac{dx}{x^2} $ diverges and that is my problem.

Comment: Let $a>0$ and write the initial integral as $\int_{0}^{\infty} = \int_{0}^{a} + \int_{a}^{\infty}$. If any integral of the RHS diverges, then the integral diverges. Else try to use comparison test or compute them directly to prove they converge.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the integrand itself diverges as $x\rightarrow 0$. This gives a clue that the integral might not converge in the given range.

The integral works out to be $\log({\frac{x}{1+x}})$ (check by taking the derivative). Substituting the endpoint $x=0$ gives $\infty$. However, the endpoint $x=1$ leads to a finite value.

If you must use a comparison test, you should find something which diverges and lower bounds the given integral.